# submit button does not appear as standard web

Tags: javascript, css, forms, button

I am developing a web application, but the submit button does not appear as standard web, like when you pass the mouse over it becomes blue, WHAT appears is only a gray background with no border this happens in all browsers, I'm sorry but I do not have enough reputation to put pictures, and also the effect sink does not appear to when you click, and it has no css yet, can someone help me or know why?

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>

*{                      margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    border:0px;
                    font-style:normal;  
                    outline:none;
                    list-style-type: none;}

body    {                   width:970px;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    font-family:arial;
                    background:#fdfdfd;}
```

the header i'm using is this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title>Painel Administrativo:</title>
<meta name="description" content="O Compareai é uma ferramenta para vôçe"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/dropdown.css" />

<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/painel_administrativo.css" type="text/css"/>
</noscript>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/pa.js'></script>



</head>
```

already tried to take off the reset but the problem persisted

Comment: Can you provide some more information, such as your platform, browser, and example code?  It sounds like there is some CSS affecting your button that you aren't aware of.

Comment: You need to post information of what systems you are using, which browser, and what your code and css looks like -- there is no information here which allows anybody to help you.

Comment: This same question was asked by him last night. He actually posted code/pictures last night though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand in your question, the problem you have comes down to the CSS rules of specificity, have a look at [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for more information.

Basically your `input` element has inherited it's properties from a parent style so you will need to create the CSS for the `input` element to make it look and behave how you want it to.

Comment: There's no inheritance going on. A selector matches the element and is applied to it.

Comment: Except for the `*` selector, that applies to every element. It's a fast reset but leads to issues such as this one.

Comment: There is inheritance going on because he said "WHAT appears is only a gray background with no border", the no border is specified in the `*{}` CSS, he needs to create a class and assign it or specify the `input` element in the CSS

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated in other answers, the problem is caused by:

```
*{                      margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    border:0px;
                    font-style:normal;  
                    outline:none;
                    list-style-type: none;}
```

`border:0px` on `*` applies to everything, *including* your "submit button", which is why you're having this problem.

If you want to use a CSS Reset, please use a real one instead of `* { .. }`:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

```
*{                  margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    border:0px;
                    font-style:normal;  
                    outline:none;
                    list-style-type: none;}
```

the * applies to EVERYTHING.  so right there you are settings the border to 0.   you need to be more specific with your css.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be with the `*` reset you're using. By declaring `border:0px;` in it, you're wiping out those styles on the input. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/yjNpR/ with the `border:0px;` property removed from the `*` selector.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and below are the results:

```
Opera:  not normal submit button, gray bg with no borders
FF:     not normal submit button, gray bg with no borders
IE:     normal submit button
Chrome: not normal submit button, gray bg with no borders
Safari: not normal submit button, gray bg with no borders
```

If you want all browsers to render with no borders and gray bg, make a class instead of using '*'

ex:

```
 .mybuttons{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:0px;
  font-style:normal;
  outline:none;
  list-style-type: none;
  }
```

and then

```
 <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" class="mybuttons" />
```

If you want it to look like a normal submit button, don't use '*{}' in your css code.